# Remove the first n Lines form txt file

Tags: r

I have this txt file:

```
c("\\f0\\fs24 \\cf0 <message messageId=\"12450\" replyToMessageId=\"0\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-12T08:42:31Z\" text=\"&gt; GBPJPY SELL 175.41&#xA;&#xA;SL:  175.955&#xA;TP:  174.382&#xA;--Trade by Grace\" />\\", 
"", "  <message messageId=\"12448\" replyToMessageId=\"12442\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-12T02:38:51Z\" text=\"&gt; SET SL TO 1.32979\" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12447\" replyToMessageId=\"12442\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-12T02:38:51Z\" text=\"&gt; USDCAD CLOSE HALF 33  PIPS PROFIT \" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12446\" replyToMessageId=\"12430\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-12T00:42:27Z\" text=\"&gt; EURAUD RUNNING 105+ PIPS PROFIT &#xA;SMALL LOT HOLDER CAN FULL CLOSE WITH PROFIT \" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12442\" replyToMessageId=\"0\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-09T14:42:21Z\" text=\"&gt; USDCAD BUY 1.3328&#xA;&#xA;SL:  1.31655&#xA;TP:  1.34473&#xA;--Trade by Jason\" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12441\" replyToMessageId=\"12430\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-09T14:25:46Z\" text=\"&gt; EURAUD CLOSE PARTIAL 69  PIPS PROFIT  MOVE SL TO ENTRY\" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12440\" replyToMessageId=\"12436\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-09T12:33:37Z\" text=\"&gt; SET SL TO 175.401\" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12439\" replyToMessageId=\"12436\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-09T12:33:36Z\" text=\"&gt; GBPJPY CLOSE HALF 34  PIPS PROFIT \" />\\", 
"  <message messageId=\"12438\" replyToMessageId=\"12430\" receivedAt=\"2023-06-09T12:32:57Z\" text=\"&gt; SET SL TO 1.60599\" />\\"
)
```

How can I remove the first 5 lines without reading the file again?

Comment: lines = elements of the vector? `x = c(...); x[-c(1L:5L)]` Everything before the sixth occurence of `/>\\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove lines from a file without reading it. However, you can overwrite the file with the contents minus the first 5 lines. Here's how you can do it in Python:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines[5:])
```

In R, you can use the readLines function to read the file into a vector, then use the writeLines function to write the modified vector back to the file. Here's how you can do it:

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
writeLines(lines[-(1:5)], "yourfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could simple do:

```
text_data <- text_data[-(1:5)]
```

This approach will remove rows 1-5. If the data is already stored in a variable, there's no need to reload it.